# Arithmetic Progression - two series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two arithmetic progressions: $a, b, c, d$ and $w, x, y, z$
If the arithmetic progressions are merged together like this:
$aw, bx, cy, dz$, is it possible to find the sum of the series?

Let $a$ be the first term and $c$ be the last term of the series.
Let $n$ be the number of terms in the series and $b$ the common difference.

$$\frac{\sin\frac{a + c}{3}\sin\frac{nb}{2}}{\sin{nb/2}}$$

Comment: The sum of what series?

Comment: It looks as if you are taking term by term products. Of course one can find the sum, just add. More generally, if you have two given arithmetic progressions of arbitrary length $n$, you can find a closed-form formula for the series of termwise products.

Comment: @chubakueno The sum of the series $aw, bx, cy, dz$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well what I actually have is $2sin2 + 4sin4 + 6sin6 + ... + 178sin178$ I know how to find the sum of a series of sin, but I don't understand what to do with the series in the coefficient.

Comment: Note that $\sin 2, \sin 4, \sin 6 \dots$ is not an arithmetic progression.

Comment: @RossMillikan Well yes, I know it is not an arithmetic progression. However, the angles are in arithmetic progression, and thus the formula can be used. However, I don't understand what to do with the coefficients that are placed.

Comment: What formula do you think can be used?  Certainly not the one for summing an arithmetic progression.

Comment: I'll make an edit to my post and give the formula. Just a sec :D

Comment: Consider that $\sin2=\sin178$. Sum your series $S$ with the reversed version of it and...

Comment: Ohhhh!!!!!!!! I see, let me try that.

Comment: @chubakueno Thank you very much!! Don't know how I missed that. Very simple thing to miss :(

Comment: @RossMillikan I updated the post to include the formula that I can use. Now I have to try to prove that formula :D

Comment: It happens more often than it should :)

Answer (score 2):

The $i^{\text{th}}$ of the first series (if we start counting at zero) is $a+i(b-a)$.  The $i^{\text{th}}$ term of your combined series is then $[a+i(b-a)][w+i(x-w)]=aw+i[a(x-w)+w(b-a)]+i^2(b-a)(x-w)$  Now you can use the sum of powers formulas to sum over the range of $i$ you desire.

Comment: I don't understand. What is b and a you have taken here? Are they the terms from my series?

Comment: Yes, they are from your question.  Because it is an arithmetic series, you must have $d=a+3(b-a)$, for example.

Comment: Hmmmmm...... That seems very complicated. There must be an easier way to do it. I have been trying for the past half hour and haven't gotten anywhere :/

Comment: It doesn't look complicated to me.  Remember, for example, $\sum_{i=0}^n i=\frac 12n(n+1)$.  All the other pieces are constants for this purpose.  This gives you an explicit formula that only uses $a,b,w,x$ and the number of terms.

Answer (score 2):

> I have two arithmetic progressions: $a, b, c, d$ and $w, x, y, z$
>   If the arithmetic progressions are merged together like this:
>   $aw, bx, cy, dz$, is it possible to find the sum of the series?

The result is $$(b+c)(x+y)+5(c-b)(y-x),
$$
or, equivalently, $$2b(3x-2y)+2c(3y-2x),
$$
or, equivalently, $$2x(3b-2c)+2y(3c-2b),
$$
or, finally,
$$
6(bx+cy)-4(by+cx).$$
*Proof:* Use $a=2b-c$, $d=2c-b$, $w=2x-y$, $z=2y-x$, and simplify.